# Given $Q:ℝ^d→(\text{Hilbert-Schmidt operators }U→ℝ^d)$, find a Hilbert-Schmidt operator $T:U→L^2(ℝ^d,ℝ^d)$ with $Q(x)u=(Tu)(x)$

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, hilbert-spaces, inner-products

Let$^1$

- $U$ be a separable $\mathbb R$-Hilbert space
- $d\in\mathbb N$
- $\lambda$ denote the Lebesgue measure on $\mathbb R^d$
- $\Omega\subseteq\mathbb R^d$ be a bounded domain
- $H:=L^2(\Omega,\mathbb R^d)$
- $Q:\mathbb R^d\to\operatorname{HS}(U,\mathbb R^d)$

> I want to define some $\tilde Q\in\operatorname{HS}(U,H)$ with
>   $$Q(x)u=(\tilde Qu)(x)\;\;\;\text{for all }x\in\Omega\text{ and
> > }u\in U\;.\tag 1$$

Is that possible? And if it is, *how*? Maybe something like a [Nemytskii operator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nemytskii_operator) can do the job.

> However, if we use $(1)$ as the defining equation for $\tilde Q$, we obtain
>
> \begin{equation}
> \begin{split}
> \left\|\tilde Q\right\|_{\operatorname{HS}(U,\;H)}^2&\stackrel{\text{def}}=\sum_{n\in\mathbb N}\left\|\tilde Qe_n\right\|_H^2\\
> &\stackrel{\text{def}}=\sum_{n\in\mathbb N}\int_\Omega\left\|Q(\omega)e_n\right\|_2^2\;{\rm d}\lambda(\omega)\\
> &\color{red}{=}\int_\Omega\sum_{n\in\mathbb N}\left\|Q(\omega)e_n\right\|_2^2\;{\rm d}\lambda(\omega)\\
> &\stackrel{\text{def}}=\int_\Omega\left\|Q(\omega)\right\|_{\operatorname{HS}(U,\;\mathbb R^d)}^2\;{\rm d}\lambda(\omega)
> \end{split}\;,\tag 2
> \end{equation}
>
> where $(e_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}$ is an arbitrary orthonormal basis of $U$. So, we need to impose the assumption that $$\int_\Omega\left\|Q\right\|_{\operatorname{HS}(U,\;\mathbb R^d)}^2\;{\rm d}\lambda<\infty\;.\tag 3$$

I'm unsure whether or not the $\color{red}{\text{red}}$ equality sign is justified. And for some reason I'm unsure whether or not $\tilde Q$ is even well-defined by $(1)$.

---

$^1$ Let $\operatorname{HS}(A,B)$ denote the space of [Hilbert-Schmidt operators](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hilbert%E2%80%93Schmidt_operator) from $A$ to $B$.